# Something between Rails and Asp.net MVC? A "best of both worlds" alternative

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-mvc

I have studied both Rails and .Net, and find myself longing for features in one that exist in the other and vice versa. Rails has a wonderfully simple syntax while the C# IDE does have features that make development easier (unless you are a command-line purist). Is there a language/framework out there that takes the best from both and puts them into one neat package?

Comment: So, basically, you're asking for a good IDE for Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like the syntax simplicity echo system of rails, and if it is the IDE, there is always ruby/rails IDEs which does same as VS for C#

- NetBeans
- [RadRails](http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails)
- [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/)

and lot more

Answer (score 0):

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)
might work for you

Comment: Scala is not a web framework, which seems to be what the question os focusing on. And you didn't indicate why you think it might work.

Comment: The question is rather vague - it talks about a 'language/framework'.  It talks about features that exist in rails and .Net. Scala is a language that has such features. Lift is the scala framwork. I didn't write any more because it wasn't clear to me if this was what the questioner was looking for, but I think that to downvote the answer is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any change had a look at JRuby w/ IntelliJ as the IDE?:

- http://jruby.org/
- http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ruby_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see the benefit of mixing ASP.NET MVC and Ruby when you have Rails. If you are looking for a IDE that's similar to Visual Studio (with ReSharper) for RoR, I would go for RubyMine. It gives you almost the same feeling as if you are working in Visual Studio.